# Getting warning in setting delegate for ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: delegates, uinavigationbar, picker, abpeoplepickerview

I am trying to build an app with the following code snippets

My Interface definition is

```
@interface CreateMessageViewController : UIViewController
```

and the method I am calling as result of Button click is

```
-(IBAction) handleEvents:(id) sender
 {
    if ((UIButton *) sender == openContact)
    {
       ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
       picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
       [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
       [picker release];
    }}
```

Now I am getting a warning for `picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;` saying

> warning: class 'CreateMessageViewController' does not implement the 'ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate' protocol

I am not able to remove the warning. Please help me out in this regard

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peoplePickerDelegate` needs to be assigned something that supports the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` protocol which your controller class doesn't (self is an instance of you controller in case that was not obvious to you).  Try

```
@interface CreateMessageViewController : UIViewController  <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> {}
```

and implement the relevant signals

Comment: I am getting an error as "error: expected identifier or '(' before ',' token" when modifying the @interface definition as suggested by you..... could you please rectify the error..... thanks

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay enough attention where/what I was copying/pasting