# Potential Memory Leak for ABRecordCopyValue

Tags: memory-leaks, abaddressbook

I am building an app that requres me to load all the contacts in the datasource of the table from the iPhone AddressBook. On running

> Build and Analyze

for the following snippet

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
int nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); 
CFRelease(addressBook);

for(int i=0; i < nPeople; i++ ){
    //ABRecordRef person = [allPeople objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *name = @"";
    if(ABRecordCopyValue([allPeople objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty) != NULL)
        name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ABRecordCopyValue([allPeople objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    [dataSource addObject: name];
}

[allPeople release];
```

I am getting a potential memory leak for the line

```
name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ABRecordCopyValue([allPeople objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

I am really tired of fixing it but was unable to. Kindly help me out.

Any kind of help would be highly appriciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't releasing the result of `ABRecordCopyValue`; try assigning it to a variable and release it and the end of the loop.  Using a variable will also make your code a lot easier to read and highlight the cause of these issues better.

BTW, you are also calling `ABRecordCopyValue` twice with the same arguments, you should only do it once (using a variable as mentioned above).

Comment: Hey could you please help me out in this as well  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991247/getting-warning-in-setting-delegate-for-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller     thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do like below:

```
CFTypeRef copiedValue = ABRecordCopyValue([allPeople objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", copiedValue] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
CFRelease(copiedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly bridge to an NSString. It may be a little more clear:

```
CFTypeRef fn_typeref = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
CFTypeRef ln_typeref = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

NSString * firstName = (__bridge NSString *) fn_typeref;
NSString * lastName  = (__bridge NSString *) ln_typeref;

NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

CFRelease(fn_typeref);    // releasing CFTypeRef
CFRelease(ln_typeref);

// use firstName and lastName down here
NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);
```

Comment: Can it be problems with memory here? Because I'm not sure that bridge makes copies of strings. But next, you release CF references and you use NSStrings after that.