# How to get an email using ABPeoplePicker?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, abpeoplepickerview

I'm not finding Apple's documentation very helpful for actually getting data with a people picker, and there doesn't seem to be much other information on the internet :( I assume I need to get the email in this function:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{

}
```

What can I put in there to get the email of the selected person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
```

After that, you can use the ABMultiValueRefs API method calls to get email address.

**EDIT** -- This should give you email

```
CFStringRef emailId = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, identifier);
```

Comment: What method calls? I'm using the line you posted, but no method calls pop up when I type [emails

Comment: Nevermind, I did CFStringRef str = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0); and that worked

Comment: @Randall: if you call it like that (with a fixed index 0) and there are no emails your app will crash.

Comment: It would be a good idea to check that you got a value in emails first with if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0) {

Comment: This answer is actually inaccurate - "identifier" is not "index". See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Kal answer is actually inaccurate - namely because "ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex" takes an index not identifier.

Identifier value is static (like enumeration)

- "Home Email" is always "0"
- "Work Email" is always "1".

So it will crash when the person selected only have 1 email stored, which is a "Work Email". Since the identifier is "1", but we need index "0".

Luckily we can use following to get the index:

```
int index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(emails, identifier);
```

Code:

```
if (property == kABPersonEmailProperty) {

    ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);

    NSString *count = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count: %d Identifier: %d", ABMultiValueGetCount(emails), identifier];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert" message:count delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    if(ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0)
    {
        int index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(emails, identifier);
        CFStringRef emailTypeSelected = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, index);
        CFStringRef emailTypeSelectedLocalized = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, index));
        CFStringRef emailValueSelected = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, index);

        self.lblEmailType.text = (NSString *) emailTypeSelected;
        self.lblEmailTypeLocalized.text = (NSString *) emailTypeSelectedLocalized;
        self.lblEmailValue.text = (NSString *) emailValueSelected;
    }

    [ self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

Comment: You should probably be releasing those CFRefs you're creating. As far as I know, "Copy" in the name of the called function means you have ownership of the returned object. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991564/potential-memory-leak-for-abrecordcopyvalue)

Comment: Or do this to give ARC control over the releases: (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, index))
Fix the release issue und it's definitely the better answer.