# How Do I Obtain A User Selected Email Address From ABPeoplePicker?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

Someone else here on Stackoverflow posted a way to obtain a user selected phone number from the contacts list. Could be done for email addresses and if so, how do I do it? Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
        ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones); i++) {
            if(identifier == ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex (multiPhones, i)) {
                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
                CFRelease(multiPhones);
                NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
                CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
                _contactNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber];
            }
        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;
}
```

Here is the link to the post: 
[How do you get a persons phone number from the address book?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117575/how-do-you-get-a-persons-phone-number-from-the-address-book)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement it as follows

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
        (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
        shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
        property:(ABPropertyID)property
        identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier 
{
    ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    CFIndex ix = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(emails, identifier);
    CFStringRef email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, ix);
    NSLog(@"%@", email); // do something with the email here
    if (email) CFRelease(email);
    if (emails) CFRelease(emails);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;
}
```